# In Stripe Payment Gateway integration, when implementing SetupPaymentSheetParameters(), googlePay and ApplePay is not taking boolean value

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate Stipe Payment Gateway and when I am using SetupPaymentSheetParameters() for card payment then GooglePay and ApplePay is not taking the boolean value, Showing error **'The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PaymentSheetApplePay?'.**

```
void makePayment() async{
    //create payment intent
    //init payment Sheet
    //display payment sheet
    paymentIntentData=await createPaymentIntent();
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters:SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret:paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
        applePay: true,
        googlePay: true;
        testEnv: true;
        merchantDisplayName: 'ANNIE';
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

These two params are not of boolean value.

You can refer to the example [code](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_sheet_screen_custom_flow.dart#L73) and see how to configure `applePay` and `googlePay` params.

Answer (score 1):

`applePay` accepts [`PaymentSheetApplePay`](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/7.0.0/packages/stripe_platform_interface/lib/src/models/payment_sheet.dart#L83-L98) type whereas `googlePay` accepts [`PaymentSheetGooglePay`](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/7.0.0/packages/stripe_platform_interface/lib/src/models/payment_sheet.dart#L100-L117) type.

You may refer to the example code for `applePay` and `googlePay` to `initPaymentSheet` [here](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/7.0.0/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_sheet_screen.dart#L97-L103).